# problemas con los CORS en .net core 7 y angular 15

Tags: angular, cors, .net-core

Quisiera su apoyo para lograr superar la siguiente situacion, tengo una api en .net core 7 y el front en angular 15, aparentemente ya configurado el tema del CORS pero solo funciona para uno de mis servicios de angular que es el de login. He intentado y revisado ya bastantes documentaciones pero no logro solucionar.

A continuación la configuración en .net

builder.Services.AddCors(options => { options.AddPolicy(name: "Global_Policy", policy => { policy.WithOrigins("http://example.com").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod(); }); });

app.UseCors("Global_Policy");

Nota: La app en Angular está dividida en módulos no se si eso influya en el problema

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y que error de CORS recibis?

Comment: Prueba `builder.Services.AddCors(options => { options.AddPolicy(name: "Global_Policy", policy => { policy.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod(); }); });`  y me avisas

Comment: @Yussef **Muchas gracias, **ya logré resolver, estaba generando mal mi jwt y me estaba jodiendo la vida XD

Comment: @Yussef si haces eso no podes mandar las cookies en el request... ;)

Answer (score -1):

El problema procedía de la generación del jwt, ya está resuelto XD